# Comparing time in NSDate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, comparison, nsdate

I am trying to compare the time from two NSDate objects but am getting the wrong answer. I think it is because when using the NSDate compare methods it is also including the date. I just want to ignore the date and compare the times. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, you can always use NSCalendar's `- (NSDate *)dateFromComponents:(NSDateComponents *)comps`