# How do I compare one time value with another?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How do I compare one time value with another?

Comment: Have a look at this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773279/comparing-time-in-nsdate)

Answer (score 1):

If it is `NSTimeInterval` then use normal operators for numeric values. `NSTimeInterval` is just a typedef for double. For example:

```
if (timeIntervalA < timeIntervalB) {
   // timeIntervalA is earlier in time than timeIntervalB
}
```

If you are using `NSDate` instances then you have several method at your disposal. Most useful is `compare`. Could be used like this:

```
switch ([dateA compare:dateB]) {
  case NSOrderedSame: // Both represent the same date
  case NSOrderedAscending: // dateA is earlier in time than dateB
  case NSOrderedDescending: // dateA is later in time than dateB      
}
```