# Incorrect date conversion from string

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have fetched date as NSString from database. It is in 24 hour's format. When I print the time that is fetched from the database, it is 06:26:00. Now when I try to convert it with following code, it gives me something really weird.

```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatttor = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatttor setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *time = [dateFormatttor dateFromString:@"06:26:00"];
    NSLog(@"%@", time); //  it prints out 2000-01-01 00:26:00 +0000
```

I need to compare current time with the formatted time. So, I need it to be converted properly. Can anyone please help.

Comment: are you by any chance living in a +6hours timezone?

Comment: To compare particular units of `NSDate` use the methods relying on `NSDateComponents` of `NSCalendar`

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9000312/2754158